# F1-12 Keys not working with minecraft

Tags: minecraft

My F1-12 Keys are NOT working for my ubuntu laptop! It is quite a pain when trying to look up my cords in my server! I need help. If you need anymore details don't hesitate to let me know!

-Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could  try resetting any one of the locations by using the following command in the terminal:

gsettings reset-recursively

For example: "gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys"

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key???

If it does, try holding it down and then pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd>→<kbd>F12</kbd> keys.

**Why???** Some laptops come preconfigured to have their special functions like volume and brightness to be pushed without the <kbd>Fn</kbd>, so to actually get the *normal* <kbd>F1</kbd>→<kbd>F12</kbd> key behaviour *of olden days*, you have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>.  **;-)**